# Changing font color in slider - Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

```html
<section class="image-slider">

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            {% for block in section.blocks %}
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{forloop.index0}}" {%if forloop.index0 == 0 %} class="active" {% endif %}></li>

            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
           {% for block in section.blocks %}

            <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %} ">
                <img src="{{block.settings.image  | img_url: 'master'}}">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5 class="title-color">{{block.settings.title}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>

            <style>
                .title-color{
                    color: {{ block.settings.title_color }};
                }
            </style>

           {% endfor %}

        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

</section>


{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Image Slider",
    "max_blocks": 5,
    "settings": [
        {
            "type": "header",
            "content": "Image Slider"
        }
    ],
    "blocks": [
    {
        "type": "image",
        "name": "Image",
        "settings": [
            {
                "type": "image_picker",
                "id": "image",
                "label": "Image"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "title",
                "label": "Image Title"
            },
            {
                "type": "color",
                "id": "title_color",
                "label": "Title Color",
                "default": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    }
    ],
    "presets": [
        {
            "category": "Image",
            "name":"Image Slider"
        }
    ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

I am learning shopify and encounter a problem regarding getting css font color. It is working fine I am able to select font color from color picker and it is applying on my slide but the problem is when i add new slide and change its title font color it applies color plus overrides previous slide title color also and applies the new slide title color to all slides . I know i am missing something here . I want my slide title color different for every slide as well as other font styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `{{ forloop.index }}` when iterating the loop, you can dynamically assign it to HTML header and your `CSS` class. That way, each block `h5` will have its own color class.

```html
<h5 class="title-color-{{ forloop.index }}">{{block.settings.title}}</h5>
```

```css
.title-color-{{ forloop.index }} {
  color: {{ block.settings.title_color }};
}
```

As the loop progresses, you are gradually building up dynamic `HTML` and `CSS`.

**first run**

```
<h5 class="title-color-1">block title</h5>
```

```css
.title-color-1 {
  color: #block-color;
}
```

**second run**

```
<h5 class="title-color-2">block title</h5>
```

```css
.title-color-2 {
  color: #block-color;
}
```

Notice how each block's `h5` class and `CSS` is now unique via its index and, therefore, not overwritten by new blocks.

Comment: This works perfectly but can you explain the logic to me @andy

Comment: @AliMirza I updated my answer with more explanation.